# id() in XPATH with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xsd

I'm trying to query XML through XPATH but is having problem getting id() to work.
I would like to get all the authors for a book, specifying the book ID.

Here's the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bookstore xmlns="http://litemedia.se/BookStore.xsd">
  <book id="ISBN9789170375033">
    <title>I väntan på talibanerna</title>
    <cover>http://image.bokus.com/images2/9789170375033_large</cover>
    <author-ref id="A1" />
  </book>

  <book id="ISBN9789170372063">
    <title>Sista resan till Phnom Penh</title>
    <cover>http://image.bokus.com/images2/9789170372063_large</cover>
    <author-ref id="A1" />
  </book>

  <book id="ISBN9789127121867">
    <title>Vårt bröllop : Kronprinsessan Victoria och Prins Daniel 19 juni 2010</title>
    <cover>http://image.bokus.com/images2/9789127121867_large</cover>
    <author-ref id="A2 A3" />    
  </book>

  <book id="ISBN9789189204966">
    <title>Människa, människa</title>
    <cover>http://image.bokus.com/images2/9789189204966_large</cover>
    <author-ref id="A3" />
  </book>

  <author id="A1">
    <name>Jesper Huor</name>
  </author>
  <author id="A2">
    <name>Susanna Popova</name>
  </author>
  <author id="A3">
    <name>Paul Hansen</name>
  </author>
</bookstore>
```

And this is my schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="BookStore"
    targetNamespace="http://litemedia.se/BookStore.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://litemedia.se/BookStore.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://litemedia.se/BookStore.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:element name="bookstore">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="book" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="cover" type="xs:anyURI" />
              <xs:element name="author-ref">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:IDREFS"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>

            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="author" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>

            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This is my code.

```
public IList<Author> GetAuthorsForBook(string isbn)
{
    using (var xmlStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(XmlDataSourcePath))
    using (var xsdStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(XsdDataSourcePath))
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();

        // Load schema
        var schema = XmlSchema.Read(xsdStream, SchemaEvents);
        doc.Schemas.Add(schema);

        // Load document
        doc.Load(xmlStream);

        // Load default namespace: bs
        var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("bs", "http://litemedia.se/BookStore.xsd");

        // We should be able to do this
        // var path = string.Format("id(id('{0}')/bs:author-ref/@id)", isbn);

        // but this will have to do
        var path = string.Format("/bs:bookstore/bs:author/@id[contains(/bs:bookstore/bs:book[@id='{0}']/bs:author-ref/@id,.)]", isbn);

        return doc.SelectNodes(path, nsmgr).Cast<XmlNode>()
            .Select(node =>
            new Author
            {
                Name = node.FirstChild.Value
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Since I've specified bookId and authorId as ID type in the schema I would like to be able to do the following.

```
var path = string.Format("id(id('{0}')/bs:author-ref/@id)", isbn);
```

This query always returns 0 elements. If I reduce it to id('ISBN9789127121867') that will also return 0 result, which indicates that id() doesn't work in my scenario. :(

At the moment I'm going for the following query, even if it's not as efficient as using id() would be, it does give me the results I need.

```
var path = string.Format("/bs:bookstore/bs:author/@id[contains(/bs:bookstore/bs:book[@id='{0}']/bs:author-ref/@id,.)]", isbn);
```

Have you ever had a similiar problem or any clue to what I might have done wrong?
Thank you!

Mikael Lundin

Comment: Mikael, the Microsoft .NET framework XSLT and XPath implementations support XSLT and XPath 1.0 and XPath 1.0 predates the W3C XML schema language so all that is defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#unique-id is a DTD based id. You seem to expect that your schema defined ids matter to XPath 1.0's id function but that is not the case. If you want schema based id to work with XPath and XSLT then you need to use a schema-aware XPath 2.0 implementation like Saxon or XQSharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in my comment, schema defined ids don't matter to XPath 1.0. 
To give you an example how it works with a schema aware XPath 2.0 implementation, here is some code using the [XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/) extension methods on XmlNodes:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings()
    {
        ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
    };
    xrs.Schemas.Add(null, "schema.xsd");
    using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create("input.xml", xrs))
    {
        doc.Load(xr);
    }

    string isbn = "ISBN9789127121867";

    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("bs", "http://litemedia.se/BookStore.xsd");

    string path = string.Format("id(id('{0}')/bs:author-ref/@id)", isbn);
    foreach (XmlElement author in doc.XPathSelectNodes(path, nsmgr))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(author.OuterXml);
    }
```

When I run that in a project where I have added references to XQSharp and XQSharp.ExtensionMethods and have added a `using XQSharp.ExtensionMethods;` it outputs the two author elements as e.g.

```
<author id="A2" xmlns="http://litemedia.se/BookStore.xsd"><name>Susanna Popova</name></author>
<author id="A3" xmlns="http://litemedia.se/BookStore.xsd"><name>Paul Hansen</name></author>
```

Comment: I see, thank you for your detailed answer. I did not know about the XQSharp project. That's worth taking a closer look at.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the XPath `id()` function is *not* implemented in XslCompiledTransform.

**For example**:

**XSLT stylesheet**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="id('a22')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Source XML document**:

```
<!DOCTYPE test [
  <!ELEMENT test (x+)>
  <!ELEMENT x (x+| y+)>
  <!ATTLIST x
     a ID #REQUIRED>
  <!ELEMENT y ANY>
]>
<test>
    <x a="a11">
      <x a="a21">
        <x a="a31">
          <y>y31</y>
          <y>y32</y>
        </x>
      </x>
    </x>
    <x a="a12">
      <x a="a22">
        <y>y21</y>
        <y>y22</y>
      </x>
    </x>
    <x a="a13">
      <y>y11</y>
      <y>y12</y>
    </x>
    <x a="a14">
      <y>y03</y>
      <y>y04</y>
    </x>
</test>
```

**Results with MSXML3/4**:

```
<x a="a22">
        <y>y21</y>
        <y>y22</y>
      </x>
```

**Result with XslCompiledTransform or with XslTransform**:

```
(Nothing)
```

Comment: Dimitre, how did you run your stylesheet? I simply added your two samples, the XML file and the stylesheet, to a VS 2008 .NET 3.5 C# project, associated the stylesheet with the XML in the IDE and then used the "show XSLT output" button and the transformation result shown has the "x" element with attribute a="a22".

Comment: @Martin-Honnen: I am using nxslt2.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Iirc (from long back) the id handling works for xdr but not xsd.

Maybe just use //*[@id='foo']